# Vertical-alignment of the index title using imakeidx

Tags: vertical-alignment, indexing, imakeidx

I want to move the index title a little bit down from the top of the page, is it possible to do it using imakeidx? Adding `\indexprologue[]{}` just before `\printindex` I can manage the space between the index title and the beginning of the list, but it doesn't affect the position of the index title.
Thank you!

Comment: `\chapter*{\indexname}` is used, so the title is at the same position as for every unnumbered chapter. There's no interaction of `imakeidx` here.

Comment: and is it possible to modify some parameters to change the vertical alignment of the index title?

Comment: Yes, of course. But it depends on your document class and other settings.

Comment: But you should think very carefully about the wisdom of making your index use a different style from all the other chapters/sections in your document. Consistency is not everything, but it comes pretty close.

Comment: This is because the proper chapter name is "indexes" and each index title printed by \printindex (i.e. names, places) should look like a section title, placed around 3cm above and not immediately above the chapter title

Comment: @Alessio -- from your last comment it sounds like you may not be using a "book" document class but one for an "article".  really, to answer this with any accuracy, it's necessary to know what document class you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the "article" class, and I finally solved the problem adding \indexsetup{level\subsection}